# SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES setting not working in Spark Standalone Windows

Tags: apache-spark

I'm trying to setup a standalone Spark 2.0 server to process an analytics function in parallel. To do this I want to run 8 workers, with a single core per each worker.  However, the Spark Master/Worker UI doesn't seem to be reflecting my configuration.

I'm using :

- Standalone Spark 2.0
- 8 Cores 24gig RAM
- windows server 2008
- pyspark

spark-env.sh file is configured as follows:

```
SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES = 8
SPARK_WORKER_CORES = 1
SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY = 2g
```

spark-defaults.conf is configured as follows:

```
spark.cores.max = 8
```

I start the master:

```
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
```

I start the workers by running this command 8 times within a batch file:

```
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://10.0.0.10:7077
```

The problem is that the UI shows up as follows:

[image]

As you can see each worker has 8 cores instead of the 1 core I have assigned it via the SPARK_WORKER_CORES setting.  Also the memory is reflective of the entire machine memory not the 2g assigned to each worker.  How can I configure Spark to run with 1 core/2g per each worker in standalone mode?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this to adding the cores and memory arguments to the worker itself.

```
start spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker --cores 1 --memory 2g spark://10.0.0.10:7077
```